# First regex instance match not matching on first line?

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex pattern per the following example.

http://regex101.com/r/sB3kK5

Essentially it just matches the first instance of the specific regex pattern.

However, as a one off derivation I can get the following to match if there is just one pattern (matches first instance with blank line & a space above the pattern).

http://regex101.com/r/eY0iC7

However, if the pattern is on the very first line then there is no match.

http://regex101.com/r/qH7iT4

How can I get that last example to match on the first line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get that last example to match on the first line?

Regex: `^(.+?)\byo\b(?:(?!cut me:|yo).)*cut me:` requires one or more characters before `by` because of `+` in `(.+?)`. Consider changing it to `(.*?)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(.+?)?\byo\b(?:(?!cut me:|yo).)*cut me:
```

I just added a `?`after the `(.+?)` to make it optional.

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/aW7dX4)